# Setting focus to next input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, focus

Currently I am creating a page. Some of the input fields have maxlength being defined, for such fields, I would like to make them possible to move focus to the next input when maxlength has reached.

Here I have the following code segment:

```
$("form input[type=text]").on('input',function () 
{
    if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')) 
    {
        $(this).next("input").focus();
    }
});
```

This code works fine in Chrome and Firefox, however, it does not work in IE. Therefore I search for the solution to tackle the issue. Some suggest to use the setTimeout() method to solve the problem.
So i modify the code to the following:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("form input[type=text]").on('input',function () 
    {
        if($(this).val().length == $(this).attr('maxlength')) 
        {
            $(this).next("input").focus();
        }
    });
}, 3000);
```

But it still does not work in my IE environment. In order to solve the issue, I have tried setInterval() too. None of the two helps solving the problem. Therefore I would like to ask how can I achieve my objective. Or the failure is only caused by I have used the setTimeout() method in a wrong way?

Comment: which version of IE do you use? as you can read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg592978.aspx `oninput` event works in IE9+

Comment: Sadly, based on requirements, the page I am building needs to support IE7 and IE8 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that IE8 and older don't support `oninput` event, as you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg592978.aspx)

But you can replace this line:

```
$("form input[type=text]").on('input', function ()
```

with this one:

```
$("form input[type=text]").on('keyup paste', function ()
```

I believe it should work even in old Internet Explorers

**Edit**

It worth to note that when `paste` event is triggering, textfield's value is not being updated immediatelly. So you have to wait an instant. The code would look like this:

```
$("form input[type=text]").on('keyup paste', function () {
  var _this = this;
  setTimeout(function() {
    if($(_this).val().length == $(_this).attr('maxlength')) {
      $(_this).next("input").focus();
    }
  }, 10);  //minimal setTimeout delay
});
```

In `setTimeout` callback `this` refers to `window` object, so you should "remember" your textfield in `_this` variable, then use it in the callback

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was busy during my weekend. Your solution is correct, the problem is caused by old verion IE does not support oninput. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For IE you need to use a settimeout function due to it being lazy, for example:

```
 setTimeout(function() { $(this).next("input").focus(); }, 10);
```

Comment: but in this case `this` would be the `window` object

Comment: @Zub:i can not understand what you mean

Comment: try this code: `setTimeout(function() {alert(this)}, 10)`.  you will see something like: [object Window]. but `this` should be the textfield

Comment: i made the second code segment based on the online reference i have read, but still IE does not respond to my code. Moreover, I have set another function inside setTimeout()/setInterval(), so based on my understanding, this inside the sub function should be the object trigger the sub-function, isn't it?

Comment: setTimeout(function() { $(id).next("input").focus(); }, 10);
I have checked this works fine, however, I still have to check condition before moving to the next input. when I add the condition, it does not work.

Comment: Maybe I can clarify it a little bit, I have tried to insert an alert into the setTimeout() / setInterval() method, the alert box does appear. However, still the sub-function which carries out the condition checking does not work.

Comment: As mentioned above, some of the input fields have maxlength attribute being set. And what I would like to achieve is when those input fields have the input value meet the maximum length, they will trigger the function and move the focus to the next input field. You can see my code in the second code segment I have attached.

Comment: You can add that part before setTimeout. and add setTimeout in condition you want.

Comment: So you mean I have my setTimeout inside another function, but afterward, inside the setTimeout function, $(this) refers to another object instead of the input field, so how should I find out the correct input field I would like to focus to?
Using id is not possible, as I have many input fields in my page need to support this feature.

Comment: @Conrad you may write `var _this = this` before `setTimeout` call, and then use `_this` instead of `this` inside